# How to get Album from facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-page

I need get all photos shared by fans in my facebook page fan. I can do?

I try using api graph but I see only album shared by me.

https://graph.facebook.com/inpesca/albums/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter to get at some specific types of posts on a wall:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/inpesca/feed?type=checkin
```

See "Searching" in the [Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

**However**, you can not use `type=photo` to get photo posts. For whatever reason, the API doesn't support this (privacy reasons maybe; I don't know). However, each post on a feed has a `type` field, indicating the type of the post. You can use this to read the feed and filter posts that have type "photo":

```
// pseudocode
posts = graph.get("/inpesca/feed")
for post in posts:
    if post.type == "photo":
        // process photo post
    else:
        // ignore it
```

To get at the actual picture, access the `picture` field:

```
// psuedo code
url = post.picture // "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/..."
```

If you look at the URL this points to, it most likely ends with `_s.jpg`. This is the "small" version of the picture. Replace it with `_o` and you will get the original version (as far as I can tell this is not documented, but seems to be how it works). You can manually download the photo with `curl` if you're on a Linux or Mac machine:

```
curl -O [url]
```

Or use your programming language's HTTP client library to download it.

Comment: maybe this is the way... but with this code I have only 2 results instead of 60... Why?

Comment: by default, the feed only gives you 25 posts, and it looks like out of the first 25 posts only 2 are photos? Try adding `?limit=1000` to the graph URL, you should see more. You can also use the paging information the API gives you to get more posts. (See "Paging" in the API reference).

Comment: Great... I have photos but i haven't source image.
I need the source path of image, could you help me?
Thanks